# Adding CSS class using offsetHeight (Javascript) causes elements to flicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have re-created a working simplified version of my issue: a skinny banner (which hides when user scrolls down), main navigation (that should stick to top of page when user scrolls down) and some dummy content to make scrolling possible.

I'm achieving this current implementation by adding a class `sb-scrolling` to the skinny banner (`display: none`) when the scroll position is less more than or equal to the `main-nav` height.

However, when scrolling slowly, there is a flicker which seems to be between hiding and showing the skinny banner. Can anyone guide as to where I've gone wrong?

UPDATE: answers below still have "flicker" present (must scroll down/up slowly to spot)

```js
      const skinnyBanner = document.querySelector('.skinny-banner');
      const mainNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav');

      // Handle page scroll
      let scrollpos = window.scrollY;
      const navHeight = mainNav.offsetHeight;

      window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        scrollpos = window.scrollY;

        if (scrollpos >= navHeight) {
          mainNav.classList.add('scrolling');
          skinnyBanner.classList.add('sb-scrolling');
        } else {
          mainNav.classList.remove('scrolling');
          skinnyBanner.classList.remove('sb-scrolling');
        }
      });
```

```css
header {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.skinny-banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
}

.skinny-nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
}

.sb-scrolling {
  display: none !important;
}

.scrolling {
  min-height: 70px !important;
}

.content-block-1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-block-2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-block-3 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="skinny-banner">SKINNY BANNER THAT IS HIDDEN WHEN SCROLLING DOWN</div>
    <div class="main-nav">
    MAIN NAVIGATION THAT SHOULD ALWAYS BE VISIBLE
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="content-block-1">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
<div class="content-block-2">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
<div class="content-block-3">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing missing is a `transition: all 0.2s linear;` in `.skinny-banner`. The rest is from @AlanOmar

```js
const skinnyBanner = document.querySelector('.skinny-banner');
const mainNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav');

// Handle page scroll
let scrollpos = window.scrollY;
const navHeight = mainNav.offsetHeight;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollpos = window.scrollY;

  if (scrollpos >= navHeight) {
    skinnyBanner.classList.add('sb-scrolling');
  } else {
    skinnyBanner.classList.remove('sb-scrolling');
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.skinny-banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
}

.skinny-nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
}

.sb-scrolling {
  height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.content-block-1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-block-2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-block-3 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="skinny-banner">SKINNY BANNER THAT IS HIDDEN WHEN SCROLLING DOWN</div>
    <div class="main-nav">
      MAIN NAVIGATION THAT SHOULD ALWAYS BE VISIBLE
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="content-block-1">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
<div class="content-block-2">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
<div class="content-block-3">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
```

**UPDATE**

`transition: height 0.2s linear;` should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT

Here is a new, different way that uses `position: fixed` for the header, so that it doesn't impact the height of the document, and we will slide the top banner off the top of the screen when we scroll down.  The main content of the document will have a 140px `margin-top`, so that it isn't hidden behind the header.

```js
      const header = document.getElementById("header");

      // Handle page scroll
      const navHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("main-nav")[0].offsetHeight;

      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const scrollpos = window.scrollY;

        if (scrollpos >= navHeight) {
          header.classList.add("moveUp");
        } else {
          header.classList.remove("moveUp");
        }
      });
```

```css
body{
  --mainNavHeight: 140px;
  margin: 0px;
}

main{
  margin-top: var(--mainNavHeight);
}

header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.moveUp{
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.centerContent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.skinny-banner {

  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
}

.main-nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--mainNavHeight);
}

.content-block {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <div class="skinny-banner centerContent">SKINNY BANNER THAT IS HIDDEN WHEN SCROLLING DOWN</div>
    <div class="main-nav centerContent">
    MAIN NAVIGATION THAT SHOULD ALWAYS BE VISIBLE
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="content-block centerContent" style="background-color: orange">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
  <div class="content-block centerContent" style="background-color: lightblue">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
  <div class="content-block centerContent" style="background-color: lightcyan">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
</main>
```

### END EDIT

How about something like this?  I stuck the skinny banner to the top of the header with `position: fixed`, and gave the `main-nav` some extra top padding so that it stays in the same spot.  We can remove the extra padding once we've scrolled down and use a CSS `transition` so it looks nice.  The other change I made was setting your body margin to 0, just to make things easier.

```js
      const skinnyBanner = document.querySelector('.skinny-banner');
      const mainNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav');

      // Handle page scroll
      let scrollpos = window.scrollY;
      const navHeight = mainNav.offsetHeight;

      window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        scrollpos = window.scrollY;

        if (scrollpos >= navHeight) {
          mainNav.classList.add('scrolling');
          skinnyBanner.classList.add('sb-scrolling');
        } else {
          mainNav.classList.remove('scrolling');
          skinnyBanner.classList.remove('sb-scrolling');
        }
      });
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.skinny-banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;

}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  transition: padding .5s;
}

.skinny-nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
}

.sb-scrolling {
  display: none;
}

.scrolling {
  min-height: 70px !important;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.content-block-1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-block-2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-block-3 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="skinny-banner">SKINNY BANNER THAT IS HIDDEN WHEN SCROLLING DOWN</div>
    <div class="main-nav">
    MAIN NAVIGATION THAT SHOULD ALWAYS BE VISIBLE
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="content-block-1">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
<div class="content-block-2">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
<div class="content-block-3">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: To be completely honest, this might be totally overkill.  After looking at this a little longer, I feel like all you need to do is set the body margin to 0, and then your original solution looks just fine to me.

Comment: By scrolling down a bit (slowly) and then stopping (not scrolling up), at some position it flickers wildly. (The banner disappear and re-appear in quick successions)

Comment: Good point, that is my bad.  Edited my answer to have a new approach - visually, I think it is good.  It does have a small potential downside that the "hidden" top banner is still technically "interactable", which means that someone could probably get focus into it with their keyboard and interact with it if they realllly wanted to.  If you don't care about this edge case, then it's not an issue.  If you do, then you can still choose to apply `display: none` to it (possibly on a short timer, so as not to break the smooth slide, but up to you).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of

```
.sb-scrolling {
  display: none !important;
}
```

it just make the `div` disappear the moment it's add to that div, so you see the flicker effect.

```js
const skinnyBanner = document.querySelector('.skinny-banner');
const mainNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav');

// Handle page scroll
let scrollpos = window.scrollY;
const navHeight = mainNav.offsetHeight;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollpos = window.scrollY;

  if (scrollpos >= navHeight) {
    mainNav.classList.add('scrolling');
    skinnyBanner.classList.add('sb-scrolling');
  } else {
    mainNav.classList.remove('scrolling');
    skinnyBanner.classList.remove('sb-scrolling');
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.skinny-banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
}

.skinny-nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
}

.sb-scrolling {
  height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.scrolling {
  min-height: 70px !important;
}

.content-block-1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-block-2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-block-3 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="skinny-banner">SKINNY BANNER THAT IS HIDDEN WHEN SCROLLING DOWN</div>
    <div class="main-nav">
      MAIN NAVIGATION THAT SHOULD ALWAYS BE VISIBLE
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="content-block-1">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
<div class="content-block-2">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
<div class="content-block-3">RANDOM PAGE CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: thanks Alan, that's a helpful explanation. but if you run your snippet, you can see that the "jitter" is still visible when scrolling down & up.

Comment: @cts what’s the "jitter"?

Comment: the issue still exists in your snippet above, have you tried running it?

Comment: By going down slowly, I can find a position where it "starts to shake non-stop". It can be reached either using the mouse and the scrollbar, or by pressing the down arrow key 4 times (starting from the top).

Answer (score 0):

When you set the display property of the banner to none it disappears from the DOM flow, and therefore changes the scrollpos value (reducing it below your threshold, navHeight). That makes appear the banner again and starts over.

If you just one to hide the banner when you scroll down and you don't want it to reappear, just set navHeight to -1 once scrollpos > navHeight.

Answer (score 0):

You can refine this even further, but the main idea is that you have the whole header be `position: fixed;` and then when you've scrolled based a threshold (say 25px)  you toggle the "`show`" class on the header.

That way you can control all the transitions, and animations directly in CSS.

And to allow space for the header, you can either fix the height of it (Which will change at different breakpoint) or you can update it when ever you toggle the class.

```js
let headerHeight = '85px';
let showingSkinny = true;

const updateCSSHeightVar = (height) => {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--header-height', height + 'px');
};

const showSkinny = (show, header) => {
  if (show === showingSkinny) return;
  
  showingSkinny = show;
  if (show) {
    header.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('show');
  }
  
  headerHeight = header.clientHeight;
  updateCSSHeightVar(headerHeight);
};

  
onload = (event) => {
  console.log('loaded');
  const header = document.querySelector('#header');
  headerHeight = header.clientHeight;
  updateCSSHeightVar(headerHeight);
  
  addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    if (window.scrollY > 25) showSkinny(true, header)
    else showSkinny(false, header);
  });
};
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  width: 100%; 
  transition: 500ms;
}

header.show .skinny {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.skinny {
  transition: 300ms;
}
.main-nav {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  margin-top: var(--header-height);
}

.block {
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}

.block:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div class="skinny"><p>Skinny</p></div>
    <div class="main-nav"><p>Main nav</p></div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="block"><p>Hello World!</p></div>
    <div class="block"><p>Hello World!</p></div>
    <div class="block"><p>Hello World!</p></div>
    <div class="block"><p>Hello World!</p></div>
    <div class="block"><p>Hello World!</p></div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "flicker" issue exists because when you apply "display: none" to the skinny banner, it triggers the scroll event on the page and the window scroll amount goes below the navheight value which then triggers the scroll event again and removes the "display: none" adding the skinny banner again and more height to the page which results in another scroll. Basically, at one point while scrolling, it gets stuck in an infinite loop of adding and removing the display tag which makes it "flicker".

The trick to fix this is considering the skinny banner's height, place a check on the second else like in the attached code and subtract the skinny element height from the navheight before comparing the window scrolled amount and it'll be fixed.

```
const skinnyBanner = document.querySelector('.skinny-banner');
const mainNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav');

// Handle page scroll
let scrollpos = window.scrollY;
const navHeight = mainNav.offsetHeight;
let bannerHeight = 0;
let skipScroll = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollpos = window.scrollY;
  
  if (scrollpos >= navHeight && !skipScroll) {
    bannerHeight = skinnyBanner.offsetHeight;
    mainNav.classList.add('scrolling');
    skinnyBanner.classList.add('sb-scrolling');
    skipScroll = true;
  } else if (scrollpos < navHeight - bannerHeight) {
    bannerHeight = 0;
    if(skipScroll){
      skipScroll = false;
    }
    else{
      mainNav.classList.remove('scrolling');
      skinnyBanner.classList.remove('sb-scrolling');
    }
  }
});
```